# Pushing data to AWS Elasticsearch from CloudWatch logs without a schema

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, aws-elasticsearch

Our setup is this, AWS Services produce and publish logs to the `CloudWatch` Service. From there we use the standard `Lambda` function to publish the logs to the AWS `ElasticSearch`

The `lambda` function pushes the logs to `ES` using the file format `cloudwatch-logs-<date>` This creates a new index every day

We have an issue with mapping of the data. So for example when a service (eg. aurora db) publish its first set of logs and the field `CPU` value is `0` the ES set that as a `long`. When that same service publishes a second set of logs and the CPU is set to `10.5` the ES rejects that set of data with the error `mapper cannot change type [long] to [float]`

We have allot of services publishing logs with allot of data sets. Is the best way to resolve this for `lambda` to push the logs with format of `cloudwatch-logs` so only one index is created and then manual fix the mapping issue for that index ? or is there a better way to resolve this ?

Comment: Can you please add the code which adds to ElasticSearch? We can then help :)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I added a link to it as it's a big function. I *think* the code is fine, its just about uploading a schema with the data

Comment: When an index is created, an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html) matching the index name can apply mappings to the new index.